# difference between $@ and $* in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

There are 4 bash snippets below. I call them with `./script.sh a b c`

```
for arg in $@; do 
echo "$arg"
done   ## output "a\nb\nc"

for arg in "$@"; do
echo "$arg"
done  ## output "a\nb\nc" -- I don't know why

for arg in $*; do
echo "$arg"
done  ##    output "a\nb\nc"

for arg in "$*"; do
echo "$arg"
done    ## output "abc"
```

I don't know what is the exact difference between `$@` and `$*`,
and I think `"$@"` and `"$*"` should be the same, but they are not. Why?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

If you have a script `foo.sh`:

```
asterisk "$*"
at-sign "$@"
```

and call it with:

```
./foo.sh "a a" "b b" "c c"
```

it's equivalent to:

```
asterisk "a a b b c c"
at-sign "a a" "b b" "c c"
```

---

Without the quotes, they're the same:

```
asterisk $*
at-sign $@
```

would be equivalent to:

```
asterisk "a" "a" "b" "b" "c" "c"
at-sign "a" "a" "b" "b" "c" "c"
```

Comment: +1 Illustrative examples help better than abstract descriptions.

Comment: This saved me from many hours of agony, didn't realized without quotes bash slices my parameters

Answer (score 10):

Difference between $* and $@ is::

`"$*" All the positional parameters (as a single word) *`

`"$@" All the positional parameters (as separate strings)`

If you pass three command-line arguments given to a bash script to a C program using ./my_c $@,

you get the result `ARG[1] == "par1" ARG[2] == "par2" ARG[3] == "par3"`

If you pass three command-line arguments given to a bash script to a C program using ./my_c $*,

you get the result  `ARG[1] == "par1 par2 par3"`

Answer (score 3):

This matters in shell scripts: for example the script testargs.sh

```
#! /bin/bash -p

echo $#

for i in $(seq 1 $#)
do
    echo "$i: ${!i}"
done

for val in "$@"; do
    echo "in quote @, $val"
done

for val in "$*"; do
    echo "in quote *, $val"
done

for val in $@; do
    echo "not in quote @, $val"
done

for val in $*; do
    echo "not in quote *, $val"
done
```

If this script is executed as `/tmp/testargs.sh a b c 'd e'`,
the results are:

```
4
1: a
2: b
3: c
4: d e
in quote @, a
in quote @, b
in quote @, c
in quote @, d e
in quote *, a b c d e
not in quote @, a
not in quote @, b
not in quote @, c
not in quote @, d
not in quote @, e
not in quote *, a
not in quote *, b
not in quote *, c
not in quote *, d
not in quote *, e
```

Thus, if number of arguments are to be preserved, always use "$@" or iterate through each argument using the `for i in $(seq 1 $#)` loop. Without quotes, both are same.