# Why the count of "arg1 $@" as bash function arguments is less?

Tags: bash, command-line-arguments

I wrote a bash script countArgs.sh as below:

```
#!/bin/bash
function count
{
    echo $#
}
count "arg1 $@"
```

I expect the output of the script should be the number of its input plus 1, while the result is like this:

```
./countArgs.sh a b c
3
```

Comment: There are some related Q&A for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008695/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-bash https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761723/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-shell-scripts https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21071943/difference-between-and-in-bash-script https://superuser.com/questions/694501/what-does-mean-as-a-bash-script-function-parameter

Answer (score 0):

You are getting count `3` because you have enclosed argument list in double quotes here:

```
count "arg1 $@"
```

And due to this `count` function is getting these 3 arguments only (in each separate line):

```
arg1 a
b
c
```

You can get same output if you place this `printf` line in your `count` function:

```
count() {
    printf "%s\n" "$@"
    echo $#
}
```

Note how first positional argument is `arg1 a` instead of `arg1`.

If you remove quotes around `arg1 $@` and call it as:

```
count arg1 "$@"
```

then you will get `4` as output.

Answer (score 0):

Two point:

first, you are echoing inside a function, it means that `$#` will give you the number or arguments or your function, not of your script.

Second, you are calling the function with parameter `$@` between quotes `"`, but `$@` already does it by default, so after variable expansion in fact it will be like this:

```
count "arg1 a" "b" "c"
```

Run you script with `bash -x` and you will see how it is working:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
function count
{
    echo $#
}
count "arg1 $@"
```